# asp.net calendar read custom attribute

Tags: asp.net, attributes, calendar

I just created a gridview to list folders from my web gallery - each folder is named like "yyyy-MM-dd " and the gridview is bound to an IEnumerable(of DirectoryInfo).
For this list of folders I'd like to offer an asp.net calendar control with existing folderdates enabled and highlighted. So far there is no problem.

Now here comes the approach: on dayrender event I add to the e.Cell.Attributes the folder path - e.Cell.Attributes.Add("path", di.FullName) .
But after a calendar day gets selected, there is no chance to read the Cell.Attributes - the calendar just offers SelectedDate and similar..

So, how can I read the "path" value from Cell attribute after a day is selected?

Or should I try another implementation instead?

Thanks in advance:) , Vlad.

Comment: Where and when do you want to read it? Why do you need it?

Comment: I need it to store the path related to the date. Actually now I realize, that if there were more than 1 folders for the date, I'd need some extended logic. So, probably, this is not a good way to handle my need. Thanks for asking! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim lblstr As New Label
 lblstr.Text ="your Text"
 e.Cell.Controls.Add(tab)
```

Try this code

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I probably thought about that in wrong way (mentioned in comments under question).